How to edit and update on React JS?
So i have UserList.jsx component which displays the  all user data in a table. enter image description here When i click on edit button it goes to http://localhost:3000/user/id. I have created a form in there to update the user details. The problem is the form is not displaying the specific user data from id. How do i do that? And how to update as well? My UserList.jsx goes like this
import "./userList.css";
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import {DeleteOutline, Block} from '@mui/icons-material';
// import { userRows, trainerRows } from "../../../dummyData";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


export default function UserList() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [selectedRole, setSelectedRole] = useState('');
    const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
    // const [sessionID, setSessionID] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
      // Login as admin to get session ID
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              email: 'rohit@gmail.com',
              password: 'password123',
          }),
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          // Store the session ID in localStorage
          localStorage.setItem('sessionID', data.session);
          // Filter the data based on user_type
          
          
          // Fetch initial user data
          // const url = selectedRole === 'All_User'
          //     ? 'http://localhost:3001/register_detail/recieve'
          //     : 'http://localhost:3001/register_detail/recieve';
          // Function to get the stored session ID
          const sessionId = localStorage.getItem('sessionID');
          
          console.log(sessionId);
          
          fetch('http://localhost:3001/profile/allusers', {
              method: 'GET',
              headers: {
                'session': `${sessionId}`,
              },
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            
              // Ensure data is an array of objects
              if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                  setData(data);
                  setFilteredData(data);
              } else {
                  console.error('Received data is not an array:', data);
              }
          })
          .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching users:', error));
            
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error logging in:', error));
  }, []);
  

 

    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        setData(data.filter(item=>item.id!==id))
    }
    const handleRoleChange = (event) => {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      setSelectedRole(event.target.value);
      filterData(event.target.value);
    };

    const filterData = (role) => {
      let filtered = [];
      if (role === 'All_User') {
          filtered = data;
          
      } else {
        // data.filter(item => item.user_type === 'trainer'
          filtered = data.filter(item => item.user_type.toLowerCase() === role.toLowerCase());
          console.log(filtered); //gives data according to filterd event
      }
      setFilteredData(filtered);
  };
  
    
    
    const columns = [
      
        { field: 'user_id', headerName: 'User_ID', width: 70 },
        { field: 'first_name', headerName: 'First Name', width: 150,
            // renderCell: (params) => {
            //     return (
            //         <div className="userListUser">
            //             <img className="userListImage" src={params.row.profile_image} alt="Profile" srcset="" />
            //             {params.row.username}
            //         </div>
            //     )
            // }
        },
        { field: 'last_name', headerName: 'Last Name', width: 150 },
        // {
        //   field: 'email',
        //   headerName: 'Email',
        //   width: 200,
        // },
        // {
        //   field: 'user_type',
        //   headerName: 'User Type',
        //   width: 150,

        // },
        { field: 'contact', headerName: 'Contact', width: 150 },
        { field: 'address', headerName: 'Address', width: 150 },
        {
            field:'action',
            headerName:'Action',
            width:150,
            renderCell: (params) => {
                return (
                    <div className="userListAction">
                        <Link to = {"/user/" + params.row.user_id}>
                          
                            <button className="userListEdit">Edit</button>
                        </Link>
                        
                        <DeleteOutline className="userListDelete" onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row.id)}/>
                        <Block className="userListBlock"/>
                    </div>
                    
                )
            }
        },
      ];
     
    return (
   
    <div className="userList">
       <div className="userDropdown">
        <select className= "userDropdownicon" value={selectedRole} onChange={handleRoleChange}>
          <option value="All_User">All User</option>
          <option value="Trainer">Trainer</option>
          <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
        </select>
      </div>
        <DataGrid
        rows={filteredData} // Use filteredData instead of data
        columns={columns}
        getRowId={(row) => row.user_id}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 8 },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
      />
    </div>
  )
}


and my User.jsx goes like this
import "./user.css";
// import axios from 'axios';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {CalendarToday, LocationSearching, MailLockOutlined, PermIdentity, PhoneAndroid, Publish} from '@mui/icons-material';
export default function User() {
    const {userId} = useParams();
    console.log(userId);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/profile/allusers/' +userId)
    .then(res => res.json()) // Convert the response to JSON
    .then(data=> console.log(data)) //Log the data
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
  }, [userId]);  
  return (
    <div className="user">
        <div className="userTitleContainer">
            <h1 className="userTitle">Edit User</h1>
            <Link to="/newUser">
                <button className="userAddButton">Create</button>
            </Link>
            
        </div>
        <div className="userContainer">
            <div className="userShow">
                <div className="userShowTop">
                    <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/admin.jpeg"} alt="" className="userShowImg" />
                    <div className="userShowTopTitle">
                        <span className="userShowUsername">Robert Kiyosaki</span>
                        <span className="userShowUserTitle">Investor</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="userShowBottom">
                    <span className="userShowTitle">Account Details</span>
                    <div className="userShowInfo">
                        <PermIdentity className="userShowIcon"/>
                        <span className="userShowInfoTitle">robert99</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="userShowInfo">
                        <CalendarToday className="userShowIcon"/>
                        <span className="userShowInfoTitle">02.01.1998</span>
                    </div>
                    <span className="userShowTitle">Contact Details</span>
                    <div className="userShowInfo">
                        <PhoneAndroid className="userShowIcon"/>
                        <span className="userShowInfoTitle">0406687956</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="userShowInfo">
                        <MailLockOutlined className="userShowIcon"/>
                        <span className="userShowInfoTitle">robert99@gmail.com</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="userShowInfo">
                        <LocationSearching className="userShowIcon"/>
                        <span className="userShowInfoTitle">Keswick, Adelaide</span>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="userUpdate">
                <span className="userUpdateTitle">Edit</span>
                <form action="" className="userUpdateForm">
                    <div className="userUpdateLeft">
                        <div className="userUpdateItem">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="robert99" className="userUpdateInput" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="userUpdateItem">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Robert Kiyosaki" className="userUpdateInput" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="userUpdateItem">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="robert99@gmail.com" className="userUpdateInput" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="userUpdateItem">
                            <label>Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="0406687956" className="userUpdateInput" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="userUpdateItem">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Keswick, Adelaide" className="userUpdateInput" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="userUpdateRight">
                        <div className="userUpdateUpload">
                            <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/admin.jpeg"} alt="userimg" className="userUpdateImg" />
                            {/* htmlFor Associates this label with an input element using the 'htmlFor' attribute */}
                            <label htmlFor="file"><Publish className="userUpdateIcon"/></label>
                            <input type="file" name="" id="file" style={{display:"none"}} />
                        </div>
                        <button className="userUpdateButton">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}


The logic i was trying to use is to append the userId at the endpoint of an API /profile/allusers. But it didn't gave me any data
